# How to insert a string after x instance of a heading tag?

Tags: php

First, thanks for helping me out here, I really appreciate your time.

Let me give you a little background on what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm working on a small site enhancement where I want to add a simple related posts widget within the content area of certain posts.

Now, for any given post, I have all of my post content stored in a variable. Let's call it $content.

What I'm hoping to do is parse this $content string and insert the widget immediately after the second instance of an H3 tag.

This is an example of one of my failed attempts:

```
$widgetizedContent = explode("</h3>", $content);
$widgetizedContent[1] .= 'widget code';
$finalContent = implode($widgetizedContent, "<p>");
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, and would appreciate any direction you could provide me.

Edit: This is the output:

```
<h3>This is my header text[this is the text I'm trying to insert]</h3>
```

Instead of inserting the widget code after the H3, it's inserting it before the closing H3 tag. I don't think I understand implode as well as I should:)

Comment: Do an `echo $finalContent` and check if that is the result you wish for.

Comment: Echo $contect and $finalContent as example and post here. By the why your implode should be implode('',$widgetizedContent)

Comment: Good call, I should have included the output. I edited the question to include that.

Comment: Are you trying to add text after second instance of <h3> (not present in output) or before first instance of </h3>

Comment: I'm trying to add it immediately after the second instance of </h3>.

Comment: Post $contect as well. The output you posted have only one instance of <h3> and only one instance of </h3>. There is no second instance of these tags. <h3> (opening tag) is different from </h3> (closing tag) Post your 'input string' and 'expected output' string.

Comment: For the sake of brevity (my content is really long), I only posted the second instance of the H3 tag. The first instance is as it should be.

Comment: Sorry for late work but I'm too badly stuck on my project. However Jong C gave a correct ans and it must work for you. If not, lets discuss more on comments in his answer. Only thing in given answer, for second instance $widgetizedContent[2] should be $widgetizedContent[1]

Comment: @KapilSharma we want to add text after the second `</h3>`, which is the third element in the array (`$widgetizedContent[2]`). The second element (`$widgetizedContent[1]`) is the text after the first `</h3>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you can add text after the second `</h3>` by pre-pending the text to the content after the tag (rather than the content before).

```php
$widgetizedContent = explode("</h3>", $content);
$widgetizedContent[2] = 'widget code'.$widgetizedContent[2] ;
$finalContent = implode("</h3>", $widgetizedContent);
```

Of course this blindly assumes there will be at least 2 `</h3>` tags, which may or may not suit your site.

Comment: Thanks, John! This is perfect.